# reescrita de url amigável

Tags: htaccess, url-amigável

Olá, tudo bem?

Preciso que a url da minha página inicial fique assim: http://meusite.com.br a url da página inicial está aparecendo assim: http://meusite.com.br/?sourceId=78902565&categoryId=5

Uma segunda página aparece como a inicial: http://meusite.com.br/?sourceId=78902565&categoryId=5

Gostaria que a segunda página ficasse assim: http://meusite.com.br/super-ofertas
ou seja, gostaria de ocultar o sourceId=78902565 e no local de categoryId=5 aparecesse super-ofertas.

Em todas as outras páginas aparece o sourceId=78902565, eu gostaria de ocultá-lo de forma que não prejudicasse as minhas vendas e no local de categoryId aparecessem os nomes das respectivas categorias, como:

http://meusite.com.br/?sourceId=78902565&categoryId=10
http://meusite.com.br/?sourceId=78902565&categoryId=20

Gostaria que aparecesse:

http://meusite.com.br/celulares
http://meusite.com.br/tv

> O meu .htaccess está assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

> O meu index.php está assim:

```
<?php
     function getHome(){
    $url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url']: ('home');           
        $url = array_filter(explode('/',$url));         
        $file = ('pgs/'.$url[0].'.php');

        if(is_file($file)){
               include $file;
        }else{ 
               include('pgs/'.'home'.'.php'); 
        };

        if((null== $file) || ('pgs/'.$url[0].'.php')== '' || ($_GET['url']) === false){
           include('pgs/'.'404'.'.php');  
               exit();      
        };       

     };
     getHome();
?>
```

As outras páginas como: contato e sobre funcionam normalmente, somente para a página de ofertas preciso de url(s) amigáveis.

É corrigir essas url(s) esquisitas que aparecem?

Desde já Agradeço a Ajuda.

Comment: veja se funciona, `RewriteRule ^sourceId\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]+)\/?$ [NC] /?sourceId=$1&categoryId=$2`

Answer (score -1):

Url ogirinal:

`http://meusite.com.br/?sourceId=78902565&categoryId=10`

Url reescrita:

`http://meusite.com.br/categoryId/10`

Regra:

`RewriteRule ^categoryId/([^/]*)$ /?sourceId=78902565&categoryId=$1 [NC]`

para deixar nesse formato:

`http://meusite.com.br/celulares`

<s>sua url precisaria ser `http://meusite.com.br?category=celulares`</s>

sua url precisa receber a categoria pelo o nome e não através do número como esta atualmente:

`http://meusite.com.br/?sourceId=78902565&categoryId=celulares`

> Para adicionar o `sourceId` basta mudar desta forma:
>
> `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/categoryId/([^/]*)$ /?sourceId=$1&categoryId=$2 [NC]`
>
> Url original: `http://meusite.com.br/?sourceId=78902565&categoryId=10`
>
> Url reescrita: `http://meusite.com.br/78902565/categoryId/10`

Comment: Olá Hebert, tudo bem?

Eu tentei o RewriteRule ^sourceId\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]+)\/?$ [NC] /?sourceId=$1&categoryId=$2
e deu erro 500.

A regra RewriteRule ^categoryId/([^/]*)$ /?sourceId=78902565&categoryId=$1 [NC]
eu também tentei até mudou a url como você disse, porém não carregou as ofertas, eu sou afiliada do buscapé e parece que quando esse sourceId não está presente na url, não carrega as ofertas do buscapé. 

Teria alguma outra solução para melhorar essas urls?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: você quer que a url assim? `http://meusite.com.br/78902565/celulares`?

Comment: Olá Hebert, tudo bem? Eu gostaria mesmo é de ocultar o número 78902565(sourceId). Teria alguma outra forma que talvez não fosse pelo htaccess, ou seja, algum código de programação no php ou html que fosse possível ocultar o sourceId e o site funcionar, normalmente, e a url ficar assim: http://meusite.com.br/celulares? Muito Obrigada pela sua Dedicação em solucionar o meu problema.

Comment: olá, essa regra `RewriteRule ^categoryId/([^/]*)$ /?sourceId=78902565&categoryId=$1 [NC]` você disse que não funcionou as ofertas? quando você diz **"não aparece as ofertas quando o sourceId não esta na url"** você se refere a não estar explicita assim: "http://meusite.com.br/categoryId/10"? caso seja isso essa regra `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/categoryId/([^/]*)$ /?sourceId=$1&categoryId=$2 [NC]` deveria resolver.

Comment: olá, eu tentei essa regra novamente RewriteRule ^categoryId/([^/]*)$ /?sourceId=78902565&categoryId=$1 [NC] e aparece assim na url: http://meusiter.com.br/categoryId/10?sourceId=78902565&categoryId=10, ele repete toda a parte após a interrogação ?sourceId=78902565&categoryId=10. E a regra RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/categoryId/([^/]*)$ /?sourceId=$1&categoryId=$2 [NC] acontece a mesma coisa, a url fica assim: http://meusiter.com.br/categoryId/10?sourceId=78902565&categoryId=10,